# Animation microphone in flutter

Tags: flutter, icons

How can I make the microphone icon like this? how can i get started

[image: the icon will start to blur when it starts to be clicked]

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/animations

Answer (score 1):

you can use the avatar_glow https://pub.dev/packages/avatar_glow package.

The implementation is quite simple.

```
AvatarGlow(
 glowColor: Colors.blue,
 endRadius: 90.0,
 duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
 repeat: true,
 showTwoGlows: true,
 repeatPauseDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
 child: Material(     // Replace this child with your own
   elevation: 8.0,
   shape: CircleBorder(),
   child: CircleAvatar(
     backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
     child: Image.asset(
       'assets/images/flutter.png', //replace it with the microhone image or icon
       height: 60,
     ),
     radius: 40.0,
   ),
 ),
),
```